# Completion of Witt ring

Tags: number-theory

Let $R$ be a perfect ring of characteristic $p$, and $f$ a nonzero element of $R$, Is it true that $W(R)^{\wedge}_{(p,[f])} = W(R^\wedge_f)$, where $[f]$ denotes the Teichmuller lift of $f$ ? Here the notation $^\wedge_{I}$ denotes (separated) completion with respect to $I$.

The question raises from Bhargav Bhatt's notes on perfectoid spaces ( [https://www.math.ias.edu/~bhatt/teaching/mat679w17/lectures.pdf](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Ebhatt/teaching/mat679w17/lectures.pdf), last sentence in Example 6.1.6). It claims there if $R$ is $f$-adically complete, then $W(R)$ is $p,[f]$-adically complete. By equivalence of $W(R)$ with $p$-adically complete, $p$-torsion free rings with perfect residue field, I think Bhatt's claim is equivalent to the question I ask above.

If $f$ is a non zero-divisor, I can argue as follows. In this case $p,f$ is a regular sequence of $W(R)$, so derived completion coincides with classical completion. By the exact sequence
\begin{equation}
 0 \to W(R) \to W(R) \to W(R)/pW(R) \to 0 
\end{equation}
we yield $W(R)^{\wedge}_{(p,[f])}/pW(R)^{\wedge}_{(p,[f])} \simeq R^\wedge_f$ and $p$ is torsion-free on the completion (Notice that if $f$ is not regular on $R$ some exactness property will fail here). So the remaining case is when $f$ is a zero-divisor, which I have no idea.